# How can Inner join with where clause select's table with hexadecimal value?

Tags: sql, hex, inner-join, where-clause

Below code works fine:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("select tbl_items.*,tbl_basket.* from tbl_items INNER JOIN tbl_basket on tbl_basket.id_items = tbl_items.id
 where tbl_basket.cookie_user = 100);
```

I get en error when I change it to this:

```
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("select tbl_items.*,tbl_basket.* from tbl_items 
    INNER JOIN tbl_basket on tbl_basket.id_items = tbl_items.id
     where tbl_basket.cookie_user = c2b32bbfd582389b7df8e89e5796aa27);
```

.

```
Error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
found: 1054 Unknown column 'c2b32bbfd582389b7df8e89e5796aa28' in 'where clause' in
```

I think the problem is with inner join, However it works perfectly without inner join.
any solution?

Comment: You need to put single quotes around the string constant.  Or prefix it with whatever your database uses to identify such constants.

Answer (score 0):

Your working query suggests, that `cookie_user` is of a numeric type. If so, prepend `0x` to the hexadecimal representation. That should work.

```
...
tbl_basket.cookie_user = 0xc2b32bbfd582389b7df8e89e5796aa27
...
```